# Need help fixing import error for SparkLine Components using React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, importerror

Receiving 4 errors when trying to run my project, seems to be not recognizing the SparkLineComponent even though I've installed the dependencies and have the correct import statements. I've provided screenshots of my code/errors.

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/w2IUA.jpg) (These are the errors I'm receiving when I try to run my project)

```
import React from 'react';
import { SparklineComponent, Inject, SparklineTooltip } from '@syncfusion/ej2-react-charts';

const SparkLine = ({ id,height,width,color,data,type,currentColor }) => {
    return (
        <SparklineComponent
        id={id}
        height={height}
        width={width}
        lineWidth={1}
        valueType="Numeric"
        fill={color}
        border={{ color: currentColor, width: 2 }}
        dataSource={data}
        xName="x"
        yName="y" 
        >
            <Inject services={[SparklineTooltip]} />
        </SparklineComponent>
    )
}

export default SparkLine
```

I'm creating a e-commerce admin dashboard app, and trying to implement charts to view income earnings, and economic progression.

Comment: Have you tried debugging by removing the node_modules, removing package manager cache (npm or yarn) and reinstalling all packages?

Answer (score 0):

When running your code on my env I have no issues so it looks like it's an issue with the module.

### Potential Solutions

1. I'm sure you did this already but just in case double check you ran this is in the terminal:

   `npm install @syncfusion/ej2-react-charts --save`
2. Also make sure that the folder you installed it in is the correct
   workspace (I'm sure you did this too but just double checking)
3. (Re-install libs) Delete all node modules then run these two commands in order:
   `npm install` & `npm update`
4. Reload your IDE (aka close and reopen)
5. If the issue persists it is likely your node settings or version - newer node versions do not support ES6 modules so you would have to require vs import.

Comment: You're welcome! 
if you liked my answer then make sure to upvote! Also if my answer solved the question make sure to mark it as accepted so others are aware of the question status! Refer what to do when someone answers your question here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers